# (Combinatorics) What are possible ways to form the equation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> What are the no. of the possible ways to form the equation
> $$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1}=2n$$ where $x_{i}\geqslant 0$ for every $i$?

my guess is $D(n+1,2n)$ but i could be wrong?

Comment: What does $D(n+1,2n)$ mean?

Comment: @Student1058 D(n,k) = C(n+k-1,k) , such that D is used for permutation where order isn't important and elements can be repeated

Comment: So then $D(n+1,2n)= C(3n,2n)$, right? If I interpret all this correctly, the result looks fine to me. Apparently this $D$ notation is exactly the equation that results from the stars-and-bars method. So I think it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots
\sum_{x_{n + 1} = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{2n}}
z^{\large x_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ x_{n + 1}}} =
\bracks{z^{2n}}\pars{\sum_{x = 0}^{\infty}z^{x}}^{n + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{2n}}\pars{1 - z}^{-n - 1} =
{-n - 1 \choose 2n} =
{-\bracks{-n - 1} + 2n - 1 \choose 2n}\pars{-1}^{2n}
\\[5mm] = &\ \bbx{3n \choose n} \\ &
\end{align}